# Can't draw SDL2 ttf font to texture

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

So I'm trying to create a texture from an SDL2_ttf font in opengl like this:

```
font->loadFont("../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 104, SDL_Color{ 255, 255, 255 }, "Some text");

void Texture::loadFont(const char *filepath, unsigned int size, SDL_Color color, const char *text) {
    TTF_Font *f = TTF_OpenFont(filepath, size);
    if (f == NULL) std::cout << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_Surface *texture = TTF_RenderText_Solid(f, text, color);
    std::cout << texture->w << ", " << texture->h << std::endl;

    GLuint result;
    glGenTextures(1, &result);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, result);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture->w, texture->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture->pixels);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

     this->texture = result;
}
```

But I keep getting this error when calling glTexImage2D:

Exception thrown at 0x03F04AEA (nvoglv32.dll) in Test Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x06EC0000.

When I try to run it with a size smaller than 104, like 24 for example, it doesn't crash but the texture only displays a few white pixels at very odd places which obviously isn't correct.

I have loaded other textures using SDL_Image IMG_Load which works perfectly fine using the same method as I'm trying with this.

Comment: Don't lie to OpenGL.  [`texture->pixels` from `TTF_RenderText_Solid()` isn't `GL_RGBA`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_42.html#SEC42).

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem